# Find particular index from the command line output

Tags: 12.04, command-line, scripts

Following is the command that find the total sinks of pulseAudio:

```
pactl list short sinks
```

Output:

```
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.hdmi-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING
1   alsa_output.usb-0d8c_C-Media_USB_Audio_Device-00-Device.analog-stereo   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING
3   bluez_sink.94_CE_2C_FA_8B_B1    module-bluetooth-device.c   s16le 1ch 8000Hz    IDLE
```

So I use the following command to find the specific sinks:

```
pactl list short sinks | grep "C-Media_USB_Audio_Device"
```

output:

```
1   alsa_output.usb-0d8c_C-Media_USB_Audio_Device-00-Device.analog-stereo   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING
```

This print the specific sink name with index. I want store this index 1 in the variable so I can use it in my another logic.

Comment: You really need to use a more descriptive title.  You didn't mention anything about ALSA or sound.  Besides that, what are you trying to do here?  Why are you trying to manipulate ALSA directly instead of using PulseAudio?  `pactl` and `pacmd` are very capable, and it's usually better to work through them than directly manipulate ALSA.

Comment: @blujay - I have edited my question.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to *do*.  I've rewritten my `~/.pulse/config/default.pa` file to turn my surround output into two separate stereo outputs, and I've written a script to automatically mute PA devices when my system suspends/resumes, so I have a little knowledge here.  What are you trying to *do*?

Comment: Please specify the exact input and output you expect.

Comment: @Jobin - I specify what exact I want, can you please look it once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you looking for,

```
$ var=$(pactl list short sinks | awk '$2=="alsa_output.usb-0d8c_C-Media_USB_Audio_Device-00-Device.analog-stereo" {print $1}')
$ echo $var
1
```